# Brute-Force encryption algo/key based on mapping encrypted-value <-> unencrypted-value (hashcat)

Tags: encryption, brute-force, hashcat

i have a list of encrypted values and i know the unencrypted values for each entry.
Is there a possibility to brute force the encryption mechanism, so that i'm able to decrypt new unknown encrypted values?

this is my list "unencrypted -> encrypted":

```
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX -> AAPBbXxBtdNhUH2nc3w3DWajRHeG5OmunJQ97n9/Ooccih07+8EsMNNW2zqbzXvQ1bl+yBwUcj1ZzcxNIem0zPr1TeiphXPh/UF9r7XzRfI4w7bMuyM=
YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY -> AALKq4wVvSIbsn3h5azSGT7Z5HKGH1YNGKC1+MVPLWKaEMHR+VbdcVcwnZYB32OHjYf/T7tpo1FjFV8qEPltpzdWxe4OFwLiB9nJe6HIan0zn4Jsf2Q=
ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ -> AANdNV4zeqvH7jVi0HjnMBkSvvAXcQavyNDOJVYUGKT/LKC97iPDB1t3xTnz/9T5kkeHxtH2lXjRnPChY3AwfVuPImQ4CF8/7sHvpQQCM3fSHAy+lV0=
...
```

The mechanism is the same for each entry (no salts).
every single value can be (en)crypted without additional values.

Is this possible using hashcat?

BR

John

Comment: Brute force is always an option, but even if there is "just" running in AES-128 ECB mode, you have 3.4028237e+38 keys to test (256 power of 16). In reality (statistically), you will find the key in the half of the testing. In 2021 there are still not enough computer resources available to run the task in an acceptable time.

Comment: Even the encryption algorithm is known, it is nor feasible (practically impossible) to extract an encryption key when using any current secure cipher. Hashcat just tries different hash from common password dictionaries.